# Removing items from LinkedList<>

Tags: c#, linked-list

i have a linked list where i store item prices. I calculated the total sum of all the items and i want to check if the total price exceeds a set limit, if it does i want to remove items until it doesn't.

So my linked list looks like this

```
Name of item: Automobilis     |Amount of said item available: 1     | Amount needed: 1     | Total price of item/s: 3000
Name of item: Kirvis          |Amount of said item available: 50    | Amount needed: 2     | Total price of item/s: 200 
Name of item: Piesiniai       |Amount of said item available: 1     | Amount needed: 1     | Total price of item/s: 1800

 Total price of all items is: 5000
```

If i have a set limit of 4000, i want to remove items until it is less than that.

I am using this method to delete the node

```
static void DeleteNode(double x, LinkedList<MatchingItems> myLinkedList)
        {
            var node = myLinkedList.First;
            while (node != null)
            {
                var nextNode = node.Next;
               while (node.Value.FinalPrice > x)
                {
                    myLinkedList.Remove(node);
                }
                node = nextNode;
            }
        }
```

But when i try to run it it throws this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The LinkedList node does not belong to current LinkedList.
   at System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1.ValidateNode(LinkedListNode`1 node)
   at System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1.Remove(LinkedListNode`1 node)
```

Comment: Your inner `while` loop is repeatedly trying to remove the same node from the list without updating what `node` points to. How are you tracking what the current total for the list is?

Comment: What is FinalPrice? If it is supposed to be the sum of all items, then your code is seriously flawed. You would need to recalculate that for each removal.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you're using `while` to check if a node should be removed from the LinkedList or not at

```
while (node.Value.FinalPrice > x)
{
    myLinkedList.Remove(node);
}
```

the first `node.Value.FinalPrice > x`, it's removed from the LinkedList, and loop keeps going, and it tries to remove the node again and again, but it does not belong to the LinkedList anymore. Change it to

```
if (node.Value.FinalPrice > x)
{
    myLinkedList.Remove(node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but if i try to use the if statement it removes every single node i think because when i try to print it to console it returns empty lines. I want it to remove items until `FinalPrice < x` .

Comment: Make sure your ‘x’ is big enough so that only some nodes will be removed

Answer (score 2):

Error is because of while!you need to replace it with `if` because after the first loop there is no node anymore.

```
if (node.Value.FinalPrice > x)
 {
     myLinkedList.Remove(node);
 }
```